# Give a combinatorial proof of the Vandermonde’s identity

Tags: probability-theory

[image]
Can anyone help me with this. I honestly have no clue where to begin.

Comment: Suppose you have two groups of $m$ and $n$ people respectively. Can you count in two different ways how $r$ people out of all the $m+n$ people can be selected to form a committee?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Question in picture deserves an answer in picture. :-P

Credits: Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Suppose we have to choose a committee of $r$ people from a pool of $m$ men and $n$ women. The LHS counts the number of ways this can be done. Now classify the committees based on the number of men, say $k$, in the committee to interpret the RHS.